# Exception occurs when trying to pass value to crystal report text box object

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to pass value from C# code to a CrystalReport report.

**Edit**

```
private void PrintOrder(List<OrderPrintBO> pListOrderBO)
        {
            DSOrderReport oDSOrderReport = new DSOrderReport();
            DataTable oDataTable = oDSOrderReport.Tables[0];
            String sOrderNo = "";

            if (pListOrderBO.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pListOrderBO.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow oRow = oDataTable.NewRow();
                    oRow["OrderID"] = pListOrderBO[i].OrderID;
                    oRow["OrderNumber"] = pListOrderBO[i].OrderNumber;
                    sOrderNo = pListOrderBO[i].OrderNumber;
                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
                }
            }

            oDSOrderReport.Merge(oDataTable);
            oDSOrderReport.AcceptChanges();

            if (oDSOrderReport.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Main Copy
                PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
                rptOrder oMainOrder = new rptOrder();

                String sCompanyName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"].ToString();
                String sPhone1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Phone1"].ToString();
                String sPhone2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Phone2"].ToString();
                String sShowOrderNo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowOrderNo"].ToString();

                ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)oMainOrder.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtCompanyName"]).Text = sCompanyName;
                ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)oMainOrder.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtPhone1"]).Text = "Tel:" + sPhone1;
                ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)oMainOrder.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtPhone2"]).Text = "Tel:" + sPhone2;
```

////This commented out section gives exception

```
 //string sVarOrderNo = "";

            //if (sShowOrderNo.ToLower() == "yes")
            //{
            //    sVarOrderNo = sOrderNo;
            //}


            //((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)oMainOrder.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtOrderNo"]).Text = "O.N. : " + sVarOrderNo;

                oMainOrder.SetDataSource(oDSOrderReport);

                oMainOrder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;


    try
                    {
                        oMainOrder.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
 MessageBox.Show("Order Printed Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in Printing Order", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
```

**End Edit**

For the first three text boxes (CompanyName, Phone1 & Phone2), every thing working just fine, but when I tried to pass  the OrderNo to the report, **Index was outside the bounds of the array.** exception is occured, even though my report have a TextBox object named **txtOrderNo**

I am not sure why this is happening. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `sOrderNo` related code is as below.

```
string sVarOrderNo = "";

if (sShowOrderNo.ToLower() == "yes")
{
     sVarOrderNo =  sOrderNo;
}


((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)oMainOrder.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtOrderNo"]).Text = "O.N. : " + sVarOrderNo;
```

**UPDATE**

Your problem is below mentioned code snippet.Inside the `for loop` you try to assign a value to `sOrderNo`. Which is meaningless.B'cos it overrides every time when loop goes.So what is the purpose of this ? If you need this value then you have to bring this value through as your table's row or as a parameter to the report.

```
if (pListOrderBO.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pListOrderBO.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow oRow = oDataTable.NewRow();
                    oRow["OrderID"] = pListOrderBO[i].OrderID;
                    oRow["OrderNumber"] = pListOrderBO[i].OrderNumber;
                    sOrderNo = pListOrderBO[i].OrderNumber;
                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
                }
            }
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: I doesn't get the difference between your code and mine except the **"O.N. : "** string. However, i tried this also but not worked. Same exception is occurring. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @V.P.Verma from where you get "sOrderNo" ? Is that using data set or which way ? put that code also on your post.